# Thinking python way - Avoiding looping

Tags: python, loops, root

I am quite new to Python.

In the code below:

Function f1, which is inside f, creates a vector I want to find the roots of. This vector is created for each line in the dataset. Its size is different for each line of the dataset and depends on n.

Function f finds the roots of the vector for each line in the dataset, keeps the second element of the root vector. In the end I sum the second element of the root vector I found for each line.

The dataset is huge so looping over all lines takes much too long.

Do you have any advice on how to avoid all those loops? It seems that it may be possible to do everything with vectors only but I can't figure out how.

Variable n is such that if n=2, var1 and var2 are non missing and var3-var5 are. If n=3, var1, var2 and var3 are non missing and var4 and var5 are.

Here is the code:

```
def f(y):  
    lf = 0  
    for index, row in data.iterrows():  
        end = int(row['n'])  
        end2 = int(row['n'] + 1)  
        rap = [0] * int(row['n'])  
        rap2 = [row['var1'], row['var2'], row['var3'], row['var4'],row['var5']]  
        for k in range(0,end):  
            rap[k]=rap2[k]  
        def f1(x, y):  
            new_list = []  
            a = y[0]  
            b = y[1]  
            c = y[2]  
            for p in range(1, end2):  
                t=p-1  
                new_elem = f2(x[0], a, b, c, x[p], rap[t])  
                new_list.append(new_elem)  
            return new_list  
        x0 = [0.1] * int(row['n']+1)  
        sol = scipy.optimize.root(f1, x0, args=(y,))  
        print sol  
        solp1 = sol.x[1]  
        lf = lf + solp1  
    return lf
```

Comment: Well... I think what you need is not `pythonic thinking` but `thinking a better algorithm thinking`. Python way does not mean magically solving problems more efficiently. Its more about writing things in a "known" solution in more readable, simpler and comprehensive manner.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Thank you for your reply. My problem is indeed that I do not manage to write a better algorithm, mainly because (I believe) I am stuck in this loop.

Comment: You might be better off putting this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @matsjoyce Ok I'll do that, thank you!